# S3 Object Creation with meta-data using CURL is failing

Tags: bash, http, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform a HTTP PUT to create and update objects while specifying a custom meta-data header. I am having difficulty generating the correct signature while I have no issue generating signatures for other requested operations. Here is my basic bash / CURL example.  Let me emphasize, I must see and use Bash and Curl, not leverage s3curl, or other libraries or CLIs in my specific situation:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

key_id="raanan"
key_secret="my-secret"
url="my-s3-endpoint"
bucket="testbucket"
path="$file"
content_type="application/octet-stream"
date="$(LC_ALL=C date -u +"%a, %d %b %Y %X %z")"
md5="$(openssl md5 -binary < "$file" | base64)"
daheader="x-amz-meta-user:qatester\n"
sig="$(printf "PUT\n$md5\n$content_type\n$date\n$daheader$bucket/$path" |    
openssl sha1 -binary -hmac "$key_secret" | base64)"
curl -k -w "@curl-format.txt" -T $file http://my-s3-endpoint/$bucket$path -vv \
-H "Date: $date" \
-H "Authorization: AWS $key_id:$sig" \
-H "Content-Type: $content_type" \
-H "Content-MD5: $md5" \
-H "x-amz-meta-user: qatester"

>>>>HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>>>>?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we    calculated 
does not match the signature you provided. Check your secret access key and   signing method.</Message><Resource></Resource><RequestId></RequestId>    </Error>
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the signature stuff are you using here? Where is the documentation on this method?

Comment: Hi, v4 signature , and documentation on this is at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html.

Comment: I don't see md5 referenced in that documentation anywhere. Are you sure you are following those directions in your code and not an older version?

Comment: Yes, I am using this successfully with PUT, GET, and HEAD requests, but only auth sig fail message when I include the meta-data header.

Comment: @EtanReisner your observation is accurate, this isn't V4. It's V2. The md5 is not part of the actual hmac signing algorithm *per se* but is used for the `Content-MD5` header, which is a component in the string to sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the `/` before the bucket name.

```
date\n$daheader$bucket/$path  # incorrect
date\n$daheader/$bucket/$path # correct
```

You are also missing a `/` *after* the bucket name in the actual URL you're handing to curl.

```
curl -k -w "@curl-format.txt" -T $file http://my-s3-endpoint/$bucket$path -vv \  # incorrect
curl -k -w "@curl-format.txt" -T $file http://my-s3-endpoint/$bucket/$path -vv \ # correct
```

With these two changes, the script works for me.

Note, also, this is *not* Signature V4.  This is [Signature V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

Comment: $date\n$daheader/$bucket/$path" does not work either. I had originally tried this way, but it was failing as well.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen!   That did it!  ----> We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK